# Dart using Null safe for variables

Tags: flutter, dart

in this below code `_invoiceInformation` in first initialize is `null` and i'm trying to use `dart` null safe to manage that in my `flutter` applications

in this code although i used `?` operation i still get error:

Error:

```
RangeError (index): Index out of range: no indices are valid: 0
```

what i want to try:

```
_invoiceInformation = Hive.box<InvoiceInformation>('invoice_information');
_province.text=_invoiceInformation?.getAt(0)?.province??'';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
_province.text=_invoiceInformation?.getAt(0)?.province??'';
```

If the list `_invoiceInformation` is empty i.e having zero elements, then the null aware operator `?` will allow you to access the element at 0, which is causing the error.

You will also have to check whether the list is empty or not before accessing its elements.

```
if(_invoiceInformation != null && _invoiceInformation.isNotEmpty) {
    _province.text=_invoiceInformation.getAt(0)?.province ?? '';
}
```